# Difference between com.azure.storage.blob.* and com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.*

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I couldn't find a satisfying answer online, so I am here. The problem I am trying to solve is that I want to download blob storage but I want the ability to start and stop a download. I see that com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.* has that ability with CloudBlob.downloadRange. I do no see that ability in com.azure.storage.blob.*.

So my question is what is the difference between com.azure.storage.blob.* and com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.*

Thank you

Comment: Can you share the links for these two SDKs?

Comment: [com.microsoft.azure.storage](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure.storage-2017-10-01/azure-mgmt-storage)

[com.azure.storage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Blobs)

Comment: update to com.azure.storage link
[com.azure.storage](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/java/azure-storage-blob/12.0.0/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`com.microsoft.azure.storage` - This is the SDK for managing storage accounts in an Azure Subscription. Using this SDK you can perform operations like create/update/delete storage accounts.

`com.azure.storage` - This is the SDK for managing data in these storage accounts especially blobs in a storage account. Using this SDK you can perform operations like create/update/delete blob containers and blobs in a storage account.

Comment: I see some azure-mgmt-storage kind of things coming under package com.azure, is it anywhere documented regarding the management API vs the usage API?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the accepted answer is correct. The explanation is on the [GitHub page for the Azure SDK for Java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java).

> Client: New Releases
>
> New wave of packages that follow the Azure SDK Design Guidelines for
> Java and share a number of core features such as HTTP retries,
> logging, transport protocols, authentication protocols, etc., so that
> once you learn how to use these features in one client library, you
> will know how to use them in other client libraries. You can learn
> about these shared features here. These libraries can be easily
> identified by folder, package, and namespaces names starting with
> azure-, e.g. azure-keyvault.
>
> You can find the most up to date list of all of the new packages on
> our page. This list includes the most recent releases: both GA and
> preview.
>
> ```
> NOTE: If you need to ensure your code is ready for production use one of the stable, non-preview libraries.
> ```
>
> Client: Previous Versions
>
> Last stable versions of packages that have been provided for usage
> with Azure and are production-ready. These libraries provide similar
> functionalities to the new libraries, as they allow you to use and
> consume existing resources and interact with them, for example: upload
> a blob. Previous library directories start with microsoft-azure-, e.g.
> microsoft-azure-keyvault. They might not implement the guidelines or
> have the same feature set as the new releases. They do however offer
> wider coverage of services.

Also, another minor difference, the license for the `com.microsoft.azure` package is Apache 2.0 and the `com.azure` package is MIT.

Answer (score 0):

In general, com.microsoft.azure is the old legacy API's package that's going away, and is replaced by com.azure.  You can find the information on their GIT repo.

- Azure Management Libraries for Java (com.microsoft.azure):
  https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-java
- Azure SDK for Java (com.azure)
  https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java

Stay away from Azure Management Libraries for Java if you just started writing Java code interacting with Azure. Although com.microsoft.azure classes are still being used in a lot of example codes, I would recommend converting those classes to equivalent ones in Azure SDK for Java (com.azure) when adopting them.